# Why am I getting different mime types on my flask app on localhost and openshift?

Tags: flask, font-face, mime-types, openshift

I have a dynamic css file which loads fonts using font-face which is generated by a request and I am setting the content headers explicitly. It's all working well as far as mime types are concerned at localhost(text/css in network tab) except that the fonts are not loaded in chrome but works in firefox. But that's a different issue, so now I put the code on openshift and by magic response has a text/html header. What am I missing here ?

```
resp = make_response(render_template('webfonts.css', fonts=fonts))
            resp.headers.add('content-type', 'text/css')
            return resp
```

heres the flask  code.

and heres the url

http://flaskexample-diadara.rhcloud.com/api/webfonts?font=LohitGujarati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue (with the Flask built-in server) and also came across your question, I found the following:

While adding the header can be found elsewhere as the recommended solution it actually doesn't set one of the properties in the Response object (which actually makes sense if you think about it) making the server still send out a default text/html header.

The way that I found it to work is this:

```
response = Response(render_template('css/' + filename), mimetype='text/css')

return response
```

You should also do

```
from flask import Response
```

Comment: I had eventually figured it out.  You can also use `response.mimetype = 'text/css'` on the response object.